# Drop down that pulls specific filtered data - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to make a task tracker (Google Sheets) that pulls up specific numbers that is filtered out from dropdown menus, and I can't seem to figure out what to do. I'd very much appreciate any help from those who knows how to make this work.

Let's say the we got 3 video editors who have been assigned with tasks, with status shown of their progress, (Pending, In Progress, and Done). And there is another column where numbers of scripts are shown. What I want to accomplish is to get each number of scripts each Video Editors are assigned with, but only those scripts that are marked as done. And to create a dropdown menu that when picked a specific video editor, autopopulates their total number of done scripts.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fy9tLJCIPMX6VJrWWKI04fLXFUB5y5akQwDICcyIa7k/edit?usp=sharing) is the link of the sheet of the tracker I am trying to make. Feel free to edit it.

Thank you for those who will try..

Have a great day.

Comment: what about `=SUMIFS(H$6:H$14,D$6:D$14,E21,E$6:E$14,"Done")`?

Comment: Hi @Harun24hr, thank you. That's exactly what I was trying to look for. Cheers!

Comment: I have posted this as answer so that you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula.
`=SUMIFS(H$6:H$14,D$6:D$14,E21,E$6:E$14,"Done")`